# Hiding table rows with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide table rows when a tickbox is checked. I have managed to get it working, but it will only hide the first instance of the id. Could someone direct me in to changing the js  so it will hide all  with matching id.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/jbntwxes/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
     if (!this.checked)

       $('#tierPoints').fadeIn('slow');
     else
       $('#tierPoints').fadeOut('slow');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints">
    <td>71</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints">
    <td>73</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints">
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

</table>
```

Comment: You need to use `tierPoints` class. You cannot you multiple `tr` with same `id`

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: No need for class identifiers neither even ids: use `$(this).closest('tr').siblings()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "**class**" selector instead of **ID** Selector and the ID needs to be unique. You can have multiple elements with same Class Name.

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
         if (!this.checked)

           $('.tierPoints').fadeIn('slow');
         else
           $('.tierPoints').fadeOut('slow');
       });
     });
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- End Of Row -->

      <tr class="tierPoints">
        <td>71</td>
        <td>1000</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- End Of Row -->

      <tr class="tierPoints">
        <td>73</td>
        <td>2000</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- End Of Row -->

      <tr class="tierPoints">
        <td>75</td>
        <td>3000</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- End Of Row -->

    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, an id has to be unique. See [www.w3.org...](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for more details.

Try to change `id="tiersPoints"` to `class="tiersPoints"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have unique `ids`. Use `classes` in this case:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
     if (!this.checked)

       $('.tierPoints').fadeIn('slow');
     else
       $('.tierPoints').fadeOut('slow');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>71</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>73</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

An *id* should be distinct within your page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints1">
    <td>71</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints2">
    <td>73</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr id="tierPoints3">
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:

As i mentioned in comment : **You need to use tierPoints class. You cannot you multiple tr with same id**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
        
        $('.tierPoints').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
        $('.tierPoints').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]{padding:0; margin:0;}


td, th {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Of Row -->

<tr class="tierPoints">
<td>71</td>
<td>1000</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Of Row --> 

<tr class="tierPoints">
<td>73</td>
<td>2000</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Of Row --> 

<tr class="tierPoints">
<td >75</td>
<td>3000</td>
</tr>
<!-- End Of Row --> 

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you all. I could not see what I had done wrong... so obvious now... my bad... I cant mark every answer as accepted, so thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Change `id` by `class`. Id is unique by definition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
     if (!this.checked)

       $('.tierPoints').fadeIn('slow');
     else
       $('.tierPoints').fadeOut('slow');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">Show/Hide</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>71</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>73</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

  <tr class="tierPoints">
    <td>75</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Of Row -->

</table>
```